# Round up double to 2 decimal places

Tags: swift, double

How do I round up `currentRatio` to two decimal places?

```
let currentRatio = Double (rxCurrentTextField.text!)! / Double (txCurrentTextField.text!)!
railRatioLabelField.text! = "\(currentRatio)"
```

Comment: Do you want to just round `currentRatio` to two decimal places, or always round up?  Ex: do you want 3.141 -> 3.14 or 3.141 -> 3.14?

Comment: Hi JAL, I want 3.149 to display as 3.15. However 3.141 should display 3.14. Thanks

Comment: See the first part of my answer for the correct rounding.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Use a format string to round up to two decimal places and convert the `double` to a `String`:

```
let currentRatio = Double (rxCurrentTextField.text!)! / Double (txCurrentTextField.text!)!
railRatioLabelField.text! = String(format: "%.2f", currentRatio)
```

Example:

```
let myDouble = 3.141
let doubleStr = String(format: "%.2f", myDouble) // "3.14"
```

If you want to round up your last decimal place, you could do something like this (thanks Phoen1xUK):

```
let myDouble = 3.141
let doubleStr = String(format: "%.2f", ceil(myDouble*100)/100) // "3.15"
```

Comment: Needs to be 3.15 if rounding up to two decimal places.

Comment: I thought the OP just wanted to round to two decimal places, rounding up or down as necessary.  Just added a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: Hi Jal, Thank you, I used your answer which worked with a slight modification as follows:-        _ = Double (rxCurrentTextField.text!)! / Double (txCurrentTextField.text!)!
                railRatioLabelField.text! = String(format: "%.2f", currentRatio)

Comment: This answers is to the question: "How to display Double with two digits in text label" or "... as string", this answer does not answer the question "Round up double to 2 decimal places"

Comment: @JAL i need olny .5 or 0 after point For ex. if we have 23.4 it should give 23.5 and if 23.8 it should 24.0

Answer (score 70):

(Swift 4.2 Xcode 11)
**Simple to use Extension:-**

```
extension Double {
    func round(to places: Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

**Use:-**

```
if let distanceDb = Double(strDistance) {
   cell.lblDistance.text = "\(distanceDb.round(to:2)) km"
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. I actually wanted to convert to the same property (double). Your extension solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: :-) Happy coding

Comment: I think yours is the correct answer. I'd just like to add a syntax modification to the func. `func round(to places: Int) -> Double {`

Comment: @23inhouse, I have updated the answer as per your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 39):

**Updated to SWIFT 4 and the proper answer for the question**

If you want to round up to 2 decimal places you should multiply with 100 then round it off and then divide by 100

```
var x = 1.5657676754 
var y = (x*100).rounded()/100
print(y)  // 1.57
```

Comment: Hi - I dont understand how you do your calculation in terms of returning a certain number of decimal. What if I want it to return 3 decimal place?

Comment: @SiphoKoza just multiply it by 1000 and then divide by 1000

Comment: This is not really the "proper" answer because internally, the number is saved in floating point, with is base 2, and you're trying to represent a base 10 number. For some numbers there is not an exact representation, and you'll wind up with too many digits when you go to print the value. The proper answer should return a string, not a Double or Float.

Comment: @levan It works for zero too, just make sure it's a double

Comment: You need to be careful with this approach. If you inspect the variable in the debugger you can see a different value (e.g. 1.569999999) even though it prints 1.57. If you need to round to 2 decimal places use a Decimal value type

Comment: Great answer, I think that this should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 18):

Consider using NumberFormatter for this purpose, it provides more flexibility if you want to print the percentage sign of the ratio or if you have things like currency and large numbers.

```
let amount = 10.000001
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let formattedAmount = formatter.string(from: amount as NSNumber)! 
print(formattedAmount) // 10
```

Comment: I have gone through many, this is BY FAR, the BEST solution! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 15):

Adding to above answer if we want to format Double multiple times, we can use protocol extension of Double like below:

```
extension Double {
    var dollarString:String {
        return String(format: "$%.2f", self)
    }
}

let a = 45.666

print(a.dollarString) //will print "$45.67"
```

Comment: Shouldn't be print(a.dollarString) ?

Answer (score 14):

**Just a quick follow-up answer for noobs like me:**

You can make the other answers super easily implementable by using a **function with an output**. E.g.

```
  func twoDecimals(number: Float) -> String{
    return String(format: "%.2f", number)
}
```

This way, whenever you want to grab a value to 2 decimal places you just type

**twoDecimals**('*Your number here*')

...

Simples!

P.s. You could also make it return a **Float** value, or anything you want, by then converting it again after the String conversion as follows:

```
 func twoDecimals(number: Float) -> Float{
    let stringValue = String(format: "%.2f", number)
    return Float(stringValue)!
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

The code for specific digits after decimals is:

```
var roundedString = String(format: "%.2f", currentRatio)
```

Here the %.2f tells the swift to make this number rounded to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 5):

[@Rounded](http://gist.github.com/abhijithpp/1cc41b41a5d1c8f007da90f20bc0c65f), A swift 5.1 property wrapper
Example :

```
struct GameResult {
    @Rounded(rule: NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode.up,scale: 4)
    var score: Decimal
}

var result = GameResult()
result.score = 3.14159265358979
print(result.score) // 3.1416
```

Comment: how can we use this with codable ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe also:

```
// Specify the decimal place to round to using an enum
public enum RoundingPrecision {
    case ones
    case tenths
    case hundredths
    case thousands
}

extension Double {
    // Round to the specific decimal place
    func customRound(_ rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule, precision: RoundingPrecision = .ones) -> Double {
        switch precision {
        case .ones: return (self * Double(1)).rounded(rule) / 1
        case .tenths: return (self * Double(10)).rounded(rule) / 10
        case .hundredths: return (self * Double(100)).rounded(rule) / 100
        case .thousands: return (self * Double(1000)).rounded(rule) / 1000
        }
    }
}

let value: Double = 98.163846
print(value.customRound(.toNearestOrEven, precision: .ones)) //98.0
print(value.customRound(.toNearestOrEven, precision: .tenths)) //98.2
print(value.customRound(.toNearestOrEven, precision: .hundredths)) //98.16
print(value.customRound(.toNearestOrEven, precision: .thousands)) //98.164
```

Keeps decimals, does not truncate but rounds

See for more details even [specified rounding rules](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/2298951-round)

Answer (score 2):

```
String(format: "%.2f", Double(round(1000*34.578)/1000))
```

Output: 34.58

Answer (score 1):

Try this , you will get a better result instead of 0.0

```
extension Double {
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
    func toRoundedString(toPlaces places:Int) -> String {
        let amount = self.rounded(toPlaces: places)
        let str_mount = String(amount)
        
        let sub_amountStrings = str_mount.split(separator: ".")
        
        if sub_amountStrings.count == 1
        {
          var re_str = "\(sub_amountStrings[0])."
            for _ in 0..<places
            {
                re_str += "0"
            }
            return re_str
         
        }
        else if sub_amountStrings.count > 1, "\(sub_amountStrings[1])".count < places
        {
            var re_str = "\(sub_amountStrings[0]).\(sub_amountStrings[1])"
            let tem_places = (places -  "\(sub_amountStrings[1])".count)
              for _ in 0..<tem_places
              {
                  re_str += "0"
              }
            return re_str
        }
        
        return str_mount
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if you give it 234.545332233 it will give you 234.54

```
let textData = Double(myTextField.text!)!
let text = String(format: "%.2f", arguments: [textData])
mylabel.text = text
```

Answer (score -6):

Just single line of code:

```
 let obj = self.arrayResult[indexPath.row]
 let str = String(format: "%.2f", arguments: [Double((obj.mainWeight)!)!])
```