# Unable to show string value to upto three decimal float value in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, floating-point, decimal

i am using like below to show string to float upto three decimal points

```
extension String {
var toThreeDecimalAmount : String{
    return String(format: "%.3f", NSString(string: self).doubleValue)
}
}

extension Double {
var toThreeDecimalAmount : String{
    return String(format: "%.3f", self)
}
}
```

and all the value types are like below.. and if  i use all values together to show in `lblTotalPrice`

```
var CURRENCY_FACTOR : Float = 1
public var currency_code : String?
public var total : String?

self.lblTotalPrice.text = "Total \(CURRENT_CURRENCY.currency_code ?? "$")\(((self.cartDB?.result?.cart?.total ?? "0") as NSString).floatValue * CURRENCY_FACTOR)"
```

**o/p**

```
 $999.12345
```

**for above value if i use `toThreeDecimalAmount` like below then the o/p become 0.0**

```
self.lblTotalPrice.text = "Total \(CURRENT_CURRENCY.currency_code ?? "$")\(((self.cartDB?.result?.cart?.total ?? "0") as NSString).floatValue * CURRENCY_FACTOR)".toThreeDecimalAmount
```

**o/p** coming like this

```
0.000
```

***i need to show like this `$999.123`***, how to do that.. please do help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round up double to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929932/round-up-double-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: @loremipsum, if i use `toThreeDecimalAmount` i am getting `0.00` bcz, here `"Total \(CURRENT_CURRENCY.currency_code ?? "$")\(((self.cartDB?.result?.cart?.total ?? "0") as NSString).floatValue * CURRENCY_FACTOR)"`

Comment: here `CURRENCY_FACTOR` is float val.. and above value is mixed types(string and float).. so how to solve this

Comment: You likely have a `nil` somewhere in that chain. check each step and see which one iid nil

Comment: Consider using [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber) that allows you to get exact representation you want.

Comment: @loremipsum, i have checked.. nothing is nil `code $, factor 1.12345, total 999.12345
`

Comment: @TarunTyagi, may i know how to use `NSDecimalNumber` in the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber) like following -

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {
    
    func roundToDecimalPlaces(_ decimalPlaces: Int16) -> NSDecimalNumber {
        let behaviors = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .bankers, scale: decimalPlaces, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false)
        return self.rounding(accordingToBehavior: behaviors)
    }
    
}
```

##### Test

```
let string = "999.12345"
let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: string)
for i in 0...5 {
    print("\(i) decimal places : \(number.roundToDecimalPlaces(Int16(i)))")
}
```

##### Output

```
0 decimal places : 999
1 decimal places : 999.1
2 decimal places : 999.12
3 decimal places : 999.123
4 decimal places : 999.1234
5 decimal places : 999.12345
```

#### UPDATE

In case you need to always round to 3 decimal places, you can go one step further like this.

```
extension String {
    func roundedTo3DecimalPlaces() -> String {
        let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: self)
        return number.roundedTo3DecimalPlaces()
    }
}

extension NSDecimalNumber {
    func roundedTo3DecimalPlaces() -> String {
        "\(self.roundToDecimalPlaces(Int16(3)))"
    }
}
```

Now your call site is simplified to this.

```
label.text = "999.12345".roundedTo3DecimalPlaces()
```

Comment: actually i want `number` should show like this `999.123` no for loop at all.. if there are any decimal points. i need to show only up to three values

Comment: thats why i am using `String(format: "%.3f"` like this

Comment: That for loop is just to show you it's behavior for different number of decimal places. `NSDecimalNumber(string: "999.12345").roundToDecimalPlaces(Int16(3))` will give you what you need.

Comment: error: `Cannot assign value of type 'NSDecimalNumber' to type 'String'`

Comment: i need to add o/p value to `label`

Comment: at the end if i use `NSDecimalNumber(string: "999.12345").roundToDecimalPlaces(Int16(3)) as? String` then it shows empty.. not showing anything in label

Comment: See the **UPDATE**.

Comment: could you please once check the code.. in hurry you might miss something...

Comment: error: `Value of type 'NSDecimalNumber' has no member 'roundToDecimalPlaces'`

Comment: You need to keep all 3 extensions in the answer, the second extension on NSDecimalNumber in the UPDATE needs the one that's defined at top in the answer.

Comment: if i print `print("code \(CURRENT_CURRENCY.currency_code ?? "$") factor \(CURRENCY_FACTOR) total \(self.cartDB?.result?.cart?.total ?? "0")")` o/p in console `code د.إ factor 3.672949 total 1399.00`

Comment: if i add like this `self.lblTotalPrice.text = "Total \(CURRENT_CURRENCY.currency_code ?? "$")\(((self.cartDB?.result?.cart?.total ?? "0") as NSString).floatValue * CURRENCY_FACTOR)".roundedTo3DecimalPlaces()`

Comment: o/p in label `NaN`.. i don't know where am i wrong.

Comment: `NSNumber(string: "999.12345")`  is expected to work NOT all the formatting around it. You need to call above function on number string without any formatting, not even  the currency symbol.

Comment: with out any formatting if i give like this `self.lblTotalPrice.text = "Total \(CURRENT_CURRENCY.currency_code ?? "$")\(((self.cartDB?.result?.cart?.total ?? "0") as NSString).floatValue * CURRENCY_FACTOR)"`

Comment: then o/p: `Optional("Total د.إ5138.45556")` but the issue is i need toupto three decimal means `د.إ5138.456` like

Comment: `let roundedValue = "\(((self.cartDB?.result?.cart?.total ?? "0") as NSString).floatValue * CURRENCY_FACTOR)".roundedTo3DecimalPlaces()` is the part where it will work.