# Swift unreliable round() method to 2 decimal places

Tags: swift, double

I'm trying to calculate the time between two doubles (distance, speed) to 2 decimal places using swift `round()` method but there are instances where its unreliable and I end up with something like 58.000000001. I tried to hack fix this by rounding again but even that doesn't work on larger numbers eg `734.00000001` Is there a way to fix this or another way to calculate time between two doubles?

```
var totalTime: Double = 0
for 0...100 {
    let calcTime  = 35.3 / 70
    let roundedTime = round(calcTime * 100) / 100.0
    print("TIME === \(roundedTime)")
    totalTime += round(totalTime * 100) / 100 + roundedTime // round again to clamp the extra zero's
    print("Total time \(totalTime)")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round up double to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929932/round-up-double-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and provide a [example], including the expected result? The code above does not compile.

Comment: @koen - pretty sure I didn't need to do this but replaced calcTime with double values representing simple math ;)

Comment: @lazarevzubov - This helped remove the values from the string output for the UI but how to remove from the Double?

Comment: If I run the code above in a PlayGround, I get 0.5 for both `roundedTime` and `totalTime`.

Comment: @koen The issue isn't related to single occurrences but over multiple run throughs of totalTime. I've further amended the code above to illustrate this.

Comment: https://timothybramlett.com/floating-point-imprecision.html

Comment: Why are you rounding at all? For display, just use `.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(2)))`

Comment: It's a nature of floating point numbers and their internal representation, one can never expect them to be precise. As links above suggest, possible solutions are formatting string output or storing numbers as two integers (that can be rounded up precisely).